# Is Thunderbolt backwards-compatible with mini-DP for both input and output?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-pro, thunderbolt

How compatible or not is the new Thunderbolt connection?

If I have a MacBook Air with Thunderbolt, can I use my existing mini-video cable to connect it to a VGA overhead projector?

If I buy a new Cinema Display with Thunderbolt, can I connect my existing Mac Pro to it?

Are there special cables, convertors needed, or are there any fundamental incompatibilities?

Answer (score 4):

Your existing Mini DisplayPort cable (VGA adaptor, etc.) *should* allow your Thunderbolt equipped MacBook Air to connect to a projector (assuming it worked previously with a Mini DisplayPort output) but, as with all things *presentation*, you'll want to test the setup in advance if possible.

According to [Apple's specs](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html), the  Thunderbolt Display requires a:

> Thunderbolt-enabled Mac computer, including MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac mini, and iMac

Your existing Mac Pro can't use the monitor.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. Very weird though... That Apple would create a display that only their computers can use. Weird.

Comment: Sounds just like Apple to me ;)

Comment: Apple is definitely more concerned about interoperability with their own hardware than providing peripherals for other makers but if Thunderbolt video is provided by other manufacturers it should work with this Thunderbolt Monitor. That being said, I agree that Apple's decision is *not* weird when viewed through the lens of Apple past. (In the olden days, Apple monitors were truly proprietary.)

Answer (score 2):

- A Projector connected to a Mini DisplayPort adapter, connected to the Thunderbolt port of a MacBook Air should work as expected.
- I don't think that the Mac Pro can currently (officially) drive a Thunderbolt Cinema Display.

You may find **[this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4885)** informative.